# How to loop through lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a task where I have to loop through a list and then dictionaries to display the total stock worth of a cafe. I created some code that was reviewed but was told these comments:

> Try looping through the menu list.
>
> Each item can be used as keys in the dictionaries, to retrieve matching stock and price values.
>
> Stock worth is the sum of each stock item multiplied by its price.

Im just having some trouble on how I would convert the list items to keys and then add them to the dictionary.

My original code was as follows:

```
menu = ['cheeseburger', 'chicken nuggets', 'fish', 'chips']
total = 0
stock = {1: 25,
         2: 20,
         3: 18,
         4: 10
         }

price = {1: 40,
         2: 35,
         3: 28,
         4: 18
         }

for stock in price:
    total = total + price[stock]
total = float(total)
print("The total stock worth is R" + (str(total)))
```

Thank you for any help and advice!

Comment: The comments are telling you that instead of using `1-4` as the keys for the dictionary, use `cheeseburger-chips`

Comment: Thank you for the advice! then why would I need to loop through the menu?

Comment: Because then you can just get the values directly out of the dictionary via `stock[food]` instead of having to use one dictionaries key as the accessor to the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
menu = ['cheeseburger', 'chicken nuggets', 'fish', 'chips']
stock = {'cheeseburger': 25,
         'chicken nuggets': 20,
         'fish': 18,
         'chips': 10
         }

price = {'cheeseburger': 40,
         'chicken nuggets': 35,
         'fish': 28,
         'chips': 18
         }


total = 0
for food in menu:
    total += stock[food] * price[food]

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets go point by point -

**1.** Try looping through the menu list.

--->  Will do this. You will understand why this is needed.

**2.** Each item can be used as keys in the dictionaries, to retrieve matching stock and price values.

---> You should use the items present in menu list as keys in dictionaries you have created for `stock` and `price` instead of using numbers for keys.

This helps to visualize and understand the code and variable structure more clearly.

So you should change it to :-

```
stock = {'cheeseburger': 25, 'chicken nuggets': 20, 'fish': 18, 'chips': 10}

price = {'cheeseburger': 40, 'chicken nuggets': 35, 'fish': 28, 'chips': 18}
```

**3.** Stock worth is the sum of each stock item multiplied by its price.

---> Now you are calculating the total price of stocks by just adding prices of all the stocks. Comment states that the logic for calculating the total stock price should be sum of `stock_units*price_of_one_stock` for each item in menu.

For doing this you need to iterate through all the items of the menu. Calculate total stock price for each item in menu and add it to final total value.

Something like this:

```
total = 0
for item in menu:
    total = total + stock[item]*price[item]
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and understanding!

Answer (score 0):

What you have been asked to do is this

```
menu = ['cheeseburger', 'chicken nuggets', 'fish', 'chips']
stock = {'cheeseburger' : 25, 'chicken nuggets' : 20, 'fish' : 18, 'chips' : 10}
price = {'cheeseburger' : 40, 'chicken nuggets' : 35, 'fish' : 28, 'chips' : 18}
total = 0
for i in menu:
    total += stock[i] * price[i]
```

The value of total, after the for loop is 2384, which is the required answer